# Assign var for SQL-Statement with smarty (Prestashop)

Tags: sql, smarty, prestashop

Hello I'd like to assign a variable in a template file from prestashop with smarty.
How can I do this?

I have following code so far:

```
{$db = DB::getInstance()}
{$id_lang = Context::getContext()->language->id}
{$sql = 'SELECT value FROM ps_feature_value_lang WHERE id_feature_value = 29 AND id_lang = $id_lang'} <- this is not working
```

Comment: Why are you generating SQL in a Smarty template? Smarty is designed for outputting pre-fetched data, not just as a replacement for PHP!

Comment: I'm new to prestashop and smarty and I already moved the code to a function in the Product-class ;). But thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the variable is inside the quotes. You need to concatenate the string with the variable.
Not tested, but it should be something like that:

```
{$sql = 'SELECT value FROM ps_feature_value_lang WHERE id_feature_value = 29 AND id_lang = '|cat:$id_lang}
```